# Search files for text matching format of a Unix directory

Tags: command-line, regex, grep

I am attempting to search through all the files in a directory for text matching the pattern of any arbitrary directory. The output of this I hope to use to make a list of all directories referenced in the files (this part I think I can figure out on my own).

I have looked at various regex resources and made my own expression that seems to work in the browser based tool but not with grep in the command line.

```
/\w+[(/\w+)]+
```

My understanding so far is the above expression will look for the beginning / of a directory then look for an indeterminate number of characters before looking for a repeating block of the same thing.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your parentheses and "+" are inside your character class: "[" and "]" define a class of characters you are searching for; including "(", ")", and "+" in between the "[ ]" means you want to match these characters among others. I think you probably want the parentheses and the "+" outside of your character class: ([/\w]+). That should match and capture any combination of "/" and alphaneumeric characters. I didn't post this an answer because I get lost trying to use regex with grep all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want a regex that will allow you to use `grep` to identify paths. I am not sure what you are trying to do with the regex you have posted. Why do you want something to be repeated? Paths only need a single slash: `/etc`.

Anyway, if you want any kind of path (paths can also contain non-word characters like `{`,`[`,`(` spaces and new lines etc), try this:

```
grep -E '/[^/]+' *txt
          _____
           |  |--------> one or more
           |-----------> A character class, '^' in a character class means NOT,
                         so this class means "anything that is not /".
```

The `-E` tells `grep` that the pattern you will give it shoujld be interpreted as an [Extended Regular Expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html) rather than it's default, Basic Regular Expression. EREs support `+` for "one or more" which is needed to find only strings with at least one non-slash character after the first slash.

If you want to find only paths with more than a single `/`, you can do something like

```
grep -E '/[^/]+/[^/]+' *txt
```

Paths can also end with a slash, if for some reason you want to keep such trailing slashes use (`/?` means "find zero or one `/`):

```
grep -E '/[^/]+/[^/]+/?' *txt
```

---

More specifically, the regex you are using fails for various reasons. First of all, as @erewok pointed out, you are using parentheses and a `+` inside brackets. Since brackets specify a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), anything within them is treated as one of the characters to be found (with the exception of `^` which makes it a [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)).

So, `[(/\w+)]+` means find any of `(`,`/`, any word character (`\w`),`+` or `)` one or more times. In any case, `\w` is not recognized by `grep` unless you use [Perl Compatible Regular Expressions](http://www.pcre.org/). You can activate these in `grep` with the `-P` flag. For example, this will match a path like `/etc`:

```
grep -P '/\w+' *txt
```

If you *know* that your paths will always consist of word characters (ie a-z,A-Z,0-9, and `_`), you can use an expression like the above but since one can never be sure, using something less strict, lke my fist suggestion is preferable.